# Can I bzr-upload only a subset of my working tree to my web server?

Tags: bazaar, web-deployment

I just discovered the [bzr-upload](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BazaarUploadForWebDev) plugin and thought it was the answer to all of my web deployment problems until I discovered one huge, glaring flaw: If your document root is in a subfolder of your working tree (e.g., `/www`), bzr-upload is pretty much useless because it uploads the entire working tree.

Is there not a switch, or at least an ugly hack, to change this behavior? **FWIW, I am limited to FTP access.** [This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-upload/+bug/530373) mentions Bazaar "views" as a possible solution (or not) and was closed with a "Won't Fix". That was two years ago, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no switch to enable this behaviour. I'm not aware of any workarounds either, other than creating a separate branch that contains just those files you need and running bzr upload on that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try your branch idea.